# Unique inputs of size n

Tags: combinatorics

Consider an input to an algorithm.

The input is an ordered sequence of $n$ numbers, each in the interval of $[a; b]$ (let $k = b - a + 1$ be the total amount of different possible numbers). Each number may appear in the sequence with the probability $p = 1/k$.

Let $v(k, n, r)$ be the number of unique inputs of size $n$, where each number comes uniformly from a $k$-sized set, and there are $r$ repeats in the input (or, there are $n-r$ unique numbers in the input).

If all numbers in the input are unique, $r = 0$, then

$$ v(k, n, 0) = \frac{k!}{(k-n)!} $$

(or $0$, if $n > k$)

If $r = n$, meaning that every number in the input is the same, then

$$ v(k, n, n) = k.$$

Can anybody please advise me on a formula for an arbitrary $r$? It's late night right now and I am not able to come up with anything intelligent.

It is possible to reformulate the problem statement if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your first formula for $v(k,n,0)$ is missing an $n!$ in the denominator, since you are considering ordered sequences.  For example, if $k=n$ then there should just be one possible input.

For $0<r<n$, to count the number of inputs you can first count the number of unique inputs of size $n-r$ (which you already know to be $k$ choose $n-r$), and multiply this by the number of ways to distribute the remaining $r$ numbers.  To find the number of ways to distribute the remaining $r$ numbers, think of each unique input of size $n-r$ as $n-r$ 'slots' for the remaining $r$ inputs.  Finding the number of ways to fill these slots is equivalent to finding the number of nonnegative solutions to

$a_1 + \cdots + a_{n-r} = r$

and this is known as the "stars and bars" problem, which has a nice formula which you can find on wikipedia's page for it.

Comment: Thanks for giving some aid! 
Why does it miss $n!$ ?

If every number is unique $(r = 0)$, there is exactly $k!$ permutations of them, so my formula seems correct.

Comment: For every set of permutations only one of them is ordered.  Say $k=n=3$ and $r=0$.  Then all the permutations are 123 132 213 231 312 321, but only 123 is ordered (I'm assuming this is what you meant by ordered)